# How to merge the Column names with the FluidRow in RShiny

Tags: r, shiny

I am currently developing a Shiny App. In that I am not getting the expected output. The expected output is

[image]

But the output I get is

[image]

This is the code used

**ui.R**

```
shinyUI(
  dashboardPage(
        dashboardSidebar(
      sidebarMenu(
        id = 'MENU', badgeColor = "aqua", 
        menuItem('VIEW', tabName = 'view'),
        menuItem('EDIT',tabName = 'edit')
      )
    ),
    dashboardBody(
      tabItems(tabItem(tabName = "edit",                      
      uiOutput("moreControls"))))
```

**server.R**

```
shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
output$moreControls <- renderUI({
      wellPanel( 
        fluidRow(column(4,wellPanel(
          wellPanel("PEOPLE", style = "background-color:#0ec3c6;border-color:#0ec3c6;text-align:center;color: white;font-size: 24px;font-style: bold ;padding: 12px;"),
          style ="background-color:RGB(255,255,255); border-color:RGB(255,255,255);align:right;",
          textInput('email', 'Enter Email_Id'), 
          textInput('fn', ' Enter First Name')))))})
})
```

Can anyone help me with this issue? Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below code will give you the required `wellPanel` layout. 
Note: I didn't use your full code, just tried to achieve specified layout. So replace the code block if it solves your problem.

```
   library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(
  wellPanel(
    fluidRow(column(4,
      fluidRow(wellPanel("PEOPLE", style = "background-color:#0ec3c6;border-color:#0ec3c6;text-align:center;color: white;font-size: 24px;font-style: bold ;padding: 12px;")),
      style = "background-color:RGB(255,255,255); border-color:RGB(255,255,255);align:right;",
      fluidRow(column(4,  "Enter Email-ID"), column(8, textInput(label = NULL, inputId = 'EmailID' ))),
      fluidRow(column(4, "Enter First Name"), column(8, textInput(label = NULL, inputId = 'FirstName')))))))

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  onSessionEnded(stopApp)
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Is there any way to remove the white spaces around People?

Comment: Please provide some explanation on how you wanted to show your `wellPanel`. Which white spaces your are mentioning about?

Comment: In the expected output , there is no white space around Project (Heading). But in my output there is a white space around People (Heading). Can you identify it?

Comment: Check the modified code. Placing the 'People' `wellPanel` in `fluidRow` removed white spaces.